# split a two-column pdf into two one-colunm pdfs

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, text-editing

I have a true pdf, +1000 pages long, written in two columns because when copy and pasting text, before reaching the bottom of one column, the cursor jumps indiscriminately in a haphazard fashion to the next column.

I'd like to use some software to visually detect where the split of the columns is and automatically split it into two pdfs.

Comment: This is most likely off-topic for [su]. Consider whether it might be better formulated and asked in [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: Do you do powershell?

Comment: @WalterMitty I am afraid it's the first time I hear about it

Comment: Ok, never mind.  It was just on the off chance.  It would be a long learning curve.  Hope you get a good answer.